# No entiendo esto en Swift

Tags: swift

```
var numerArray = [Int]()


numerArray.append(01)
numerArray.append(02)
numerArray.append(03)


for x in numerArray{
    print("numero: \(x)")
}


numerArray.remove(at: 0)
numerArray.append(04)

for i in numerArray[0...(numerArray.count-1)]{ //No estiendo la utilidad del -1 al final del           metodo count
print("numero: \(i)")
}
```

//No entiendo , en principio el -1 seria para restarle 1 o como, soy nuevo en esto de la programación, llevo un par de meses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te lo explico, esto no solo se aplica a **Swift**, sino a muchos otros lenguajes de programación.

Que ocurre? en un bucle `for` empezamos a contar desde 0 hasta un numero X, este numero, como ejemplo, puede ser el final de un array (`numerArray`).

Pues si este array tiene 5 elementos (0,1,2,3,4), no puedes acceder a la posicion 5 que no existe
te lo explico con una imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como puedes ver, la propiedad `count` nos devolvera **5**, pero esto causara un error, pues los indices empiezan por **0**, por ese motivo siempre se resta 1.

Comment: muchas gracias, ahora si lo entiendo, de veras gracias!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Si la respuesta te a resultado util, marcala como respuestas por favor ;)